# E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Tags: delphi, pascal, indy, indy10

I have this line of code throwing up the above error:

```
server:=TIdHTTPServer.Create;
server.OnQuerySSLPort(8092,true);
```

I've read about using the right vars/constants but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help, appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `var` parameter is passed by reference (that is, the method doesn't want only a value, but a *variable* (which comes with a value), which it can alter if necessary), so you need to pass a variable (of the right type), not only a value. This works:

```
var
  mybool: boolean;
begin
  mybool := true;

  server := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
  server.OnQuerySSLPort(8092, mybool);
  // Now mybool can be either true or false; it's up to the method.
```